# Angular + Bootstrap Responsive Design + Data Grid (DataTables/UI Grid)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, angular-ui, ng-grid

I have a large collection of data to display in a datagrid (1000+ records). I want to have this grid to be responsive and lazy load the data with Angular bindings. The Application requirement does not allow me to use Pagination concepts.

The Test/Pan, Results, Additional Info are clickable links which would display inline contents in the same row (like detail row with variable heights).

I am not sure how to approach this kind of design inside a datagrid like using JQuery DataTables or Angular UI Grid. I am sure that it can be displayed using bootstrap table but number of bindings would be a problem doing it in Angular way with 1000+ rows. Each row would have 50+ properties.

I am not a designer and not sure how to attack it. Any expert direction would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: For the usability component, I'd check out http://ux.stackexchange.com/.  Also, 1000+ and there's a business requirement to see them all on the same screen?  Unless you zoom out *really far* that's never going to happen simultaneously.  It might be better to just implement sorting and searching.  I don't know about the performance issue, but I wouldn't get into early optimization.  Get a working sample up an running.  Come back here if you get stuck or go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it's completely done and you want someone to help tell you if it's efficient.

Comment: thanks for checking on it. As you said, I will first make it work before thinking about optimizing it. For now, I started to put it with bootstrap table